# Finding an example of an integral non separated scheme $X$, with $U \subsetneq X$ open and a retraction $X \to U$.

Tags: algebraic-geometry

I proved that if $X$ is an integral and separated scheme and $U$ an open subscheme s.t.the map $X \to U$ restricted to $U$ is the identity of $U$ then $U$ is also a closed immersion and as a consequence $X=U$.
but I don't find an example of an integral scheme $X$ which is not separated and an open subscheme $U$  s.t, the map $X \to U$ restricted to $U$ is the identity of $U$ and $X \neq U$.
can anyone help?

I thought of $X=\operatorname{Spec} k[X,Y]$ and $U=D(X)D(Y)$ but I don't think the restriction of $X \to U$ is $U$.

Comment: For some basic information about writing mathematics at this site see, *e.g.*, [here](/help/notation), [here](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020), [here](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559) and [here](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1773).

Answer (score 1):

Take $X$ to be the affine line with doubled origin over $\mathbb{C}$, and the natural map $X \to \mathbb{A}^1_{\mathbb{C}}$.